# Android sign in with google,with server side java

Tags: java, android, server

I am working on client(android) and server side(Java)to login with google.In the android side ,I got the cliend id and the access token,but I need to verify the access token and get user info in the server side ,I followed this link https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth but I cannot understand the flow.Also I got a syntax error "syntax error on token expected" on 
       GoogleIdToken idToken = verifier.verify(idTokenString);
idTokenString is the string token that got from android side.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue and understand the flow.
Here is my code:

```
  package com.secret.secret.utils;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.util.Collections;
  import java.util.logging.Logger;

  import javax.servlet.ServletException;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

  import org.apache.catalina.Authenticator;
  import org.apache.catalina.connector.Request;

  import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken;
  import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken.Payload;
  import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdTokenVerifier;
  import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
  import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
  public class GoogleUtil  {


private HttpTransport transport;

private JsonFactory jsonFactory;
String clientId="My client Id";

GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(transport, jsonFactory)
        .setAudience(Collections.singletonList(clientId))
        // Or, if multiple clients access the backend:
        //.setAudience(Arrays.asList(CLIENT_ID_1, CLIENT_ID_2, CLIENT_ID_3))
        .build();

private GoogleIdToken idTokenString;

    // (Receive idTokenString by HTTPS POST)

    GoogleIdToken idToken = verifier.verify(idTokenString);
    if (idToken != null) {
      Payload payload = idToken.getPayload();

      // Print user identifier
      String userId = payload.getSubject();
      System.out.println("User ID: " + userId);

      // Get profile information from payload
      String email = payload.getEmail();
      boolean emailVerified = Boolean.valueOf(payload.getEmailVerified());
      String name = (String) payload.get("name");
      String pictureUrl = (String) payload.get("picture");
      String locale = (String) payload.get("locale");
      String familyName = (String) payload.get("family_name");
      String givenName = (String) payload.get("given_name");

      // Use or store profile information
      // ...

    } else {
      System.out.println("Invalid ID token.");
    }

   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

On your android client side:

```
public void handleSigninResult(GoogleSignInResult signInResult){
    if (signInResult.isSuccess()){
        GoogleSignInAccount account = signInResult.getSignInAccount();
        String idToken = account.getIdToken();

        //use this idToken in your server-side verification
    }
}
```